# Unknown Race distances

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(Can you please explain clearly how you found the solution to this question as I'm only a Year 7)

In a $5000$ m race, the winner finishes $200$ metres ahead of second and $600$ metres ahead of third. Assuming the runners run at a constant speed, to the nearest integer how many metres ahead of third will second finish?

I tried using $$\text{time}=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}$$

formula and I replaced it with the distances between them and pro-numerals for the speed, but then I got stuck. I found out the answer in the internet to be  $417$ m but I didn't understand how they got the answer because it was in Year 9 format. Can anyone help me?

P.S. This is the answer I didn't understand
[image]

Comment: Do we know the finishing time of the winner?

Comment: How can the answer be 417 *meters* when the question is how many *seconds*? That's like asking, how old are you? and answering, 13 kilograms.

Comment: Oh sorry I'll edit

Comment: In the length of time it takes #2 to run 4800 meters, #3 runs 4400 meters. So, in the time it takes #2 to run 5000 meters, how far will #3 run?

Comment: @GerryMyerson By your logic, the answer should be 400m but it's 417. Why?

Comment: No, bio, that's your logic, not mine. I've asked a question, and you've given the wrong answer. The logical extension of *your* reasoning is that in the time #2 runs 200 meters, #3 will run $-200$ meters, which is ridiculous. So, think about it – in the time #2 runs 200 meters, how far does #3 run?

Comment: If you want an answer you can understand, maybe you should show us the answer you did _not_ understand, and explain why you could not understand it. Then someone may either be able to explain it or to solve the problem without the confusing parts.

Comment: I'm trying to show a picture but I can't get it up. Anyway, here's the  [link](http://enrichedmaths.maths.uwa.edu.au/wajo/qnsandsolns/wajo16qnsoln.pdf). Look for the answer in the answer section.

Comment: I added a photo

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_1$ be the finish time for the winner and $t_2$ be the finish time of the second.

\begin{align*}
  v_1 t_1 &= 5000 \\
  v_2 t_1 &= 4800 \\
  v_3 t_1 &= 4400 \\
  v_2 t_2 &= 5000 \\
  v_3 t_2 &= \frac{4400}{t_1} \times \frac{5000}{v_2} \\
  &= \frac{4400 \times 5000}{4800} \\
  v_2 t_2-v_3t_2 &= 5000 -\frac{4400 \times 5000}{4800} \\
  &\approx 417 \; \text{m} 
\end{align*}

Comment: what are the v's for?

Comment: $v_1$ velocity (or speed) of the first, $v_2$ velocity of the second, etc.

Comment: Well, it works, but it's much too hard. There's no need to introduce five variables – or *any* variables – into an arithmetic problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, the model answer (updated in the post) does involve $5$ variables as mine.

Comment: Maybe that's why bio couldn't understand it.